# My Acer leaves are dying as they shoot

Tags: leaves, wilt

⁸[image: Acer with wilting leaves]

My acer is 2 years old now, I had a problem with scorch last year. This year it started sprouting lovely but now it looks like the new leaves are dead or dying. The red leaves that are there are very soft and wilted. I'm gutted.

Comment: Also site can't upload other photos I have they say pic is too big?

Comment: Where are you in the world (for weather/climate purposes)? Is that pot the same one its been in for two years? Does it have drainage holes?

Comment: Hi I'm in the south of the UK. No I changed the pot for a bigger one after 1st year. It was fine last season but it did suffer with a windy couple of weeks we had

Comment: Yes the pot has drainage,  is it possible I've under watered? I didn't think I had . The red leaves are very floppy and soft, is there any way to bring it back?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's suffered drought, or at least insufficient water supplies, and also suffered quite a bit of wind damage, possibly even hot sun after a cold night, but the wind is more likely. I'm not seeing any die back, though it does look a bit of a mess, so hard to say for sure if there's another problem going on, and I can't see the whole plant - just inspect closely all stems, including the main stem down to soil level, and backs of leaves to make sure there's nothing there that shouldn't be, like scale insect or other damage. Hopefully, when you repotted, you used new potting soil - the best one to use would have been John Innes No. 3.

Acers prefer a very sheltered spot, preferably not in full sun, but partial sun, with soil that doesn't completely dry out regularly. I don't know your watering regime, but it should  be watered when the surface of the soil is just about dry to the touch, and watered thoroughly with a good few litres (3-5 litres maybe) such that the excess runs freely out the bottom of the pot. If it's in an exposed position, find a more  sheltered spot, but it would likely do better in the ground ongoing - the time to transfer it to the ground is autumn, not now.

Comment: Ah thanks for your comments , maybe drought then as although we've had quite a bit of rain when it first started sprouting I didnt water as much as I do now. I used Ericaceous compost when repotted as recommended for Acers. I have no ground in the garden to plant it as it was all slabbed and now  fake grass with pots. Should it come back this year? The stems look fine, no mites?

Comment: Fingers crossed! If there's no disease or infestation  problems it should recover with improved watering- remember that when it rains, not much rain gets into pots, unless its torrential, so you can't skip watering I'm afraid. I forgot to say, remove any dead tips to stems and any damaged stems, back to where there's growth or growth buds.

Comment: Thankyou I will do and I'll keep you posted x